# How to use the database that is updating by transactions log shipping service

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Not so far ago I was faced with the trouble of dynamically transferring data from one database to another.
The only reason to do that for me is when first database server go down, the system can use second server.
For this purpose i used Transaction Log Shipping service.
As far as i can see, it working fine now and copying logs from one server to another every 15 min.

My question is, when the critical moment comes, and the first server will down, how can i use the database on the second server?

As i can see now, the database says that it "Restoring..." and i can do nothing with it.
I understand that this is because it staying in sync with first server.
But when i need that database, how can i switch it into normal mode, when i can query it and modify ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It should not be in the restoring state. It should be in 'read-only' mode. As far as I remember setting this thing up. So you basically strip the read-only mode and use it as if it were your primary database.